# Any way of making 2 abstract classes with a generic type of the other one?

Tags: c#, class, generics

I'm creating a library for my Socket TCP servers.

I want my BaseServer class to take a BaseUser as generic type and the BaseUser to take a BaseServer as generic type (they are abstract classes).

Both classes will need their type in the where clause of the type.

How can i manage to make it work ?

BaseServer.cs

```cs
public abstract class BaseServer<UserType> where UserType : BaseUser//Need <BaseServerChildrenType>
{
    public List<UserType> Users { get; protected set; }
}
```

BaseUser.cs

```cs
public abstract class BaseUser<ServerType> where ServerType : BaseServer//Need <BaseUserChildrenType>
{
    public ServerType server { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `BaseUser` an example of `BaseClient`?

Comment: No, you can't really, because it would require a recursive pattern. You can try a different pattern, e.g. 
 `BaseSession<UserType,ServerType>` (use a 2-arity generic). Or you could give one of your types a second, non-generic interface, and use that in the type constraint for your generic type. Or use non-generic polymorphism.

Comment: HereticMonkey i fixed my post, `BaseClient` was `BaseUser` actually.

JohnWu what would be `BaseSession` for `BaseServer` and `BaseUser` ?

Comment: A friend told me to create 2 interfaces `IBaseServer` and `IBaseUser` and to use `where ServerType : IBaseServer` Would that be a good solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that can help:

```
public interface IBaseUser
{ }

public interface IBaseServer
{ }

public abstract class BaseServer<UserType> where UserType : IBaseUser//Need <BaseServerChildrenType>
{
    public List<UserType> Users { get; protected set; }
}

public abstract class BaseUser<ServerType> where ServerType : IBaseServer//Need <BaseUserChildrenType>
{
    public ServerType server { get; private set; }
}

public class Server1 : BaseServer<User1>, IBaseServer
{ }

public class User1 : BaseUser<Server1>, IBaseUser
{ }
```

Option 2, so you don't need to implement the interface in any deriverd class:

```
public interface IBaseUser
{ }

public interface IBaseServer
{ }

public abstract class BaseServer<UserType> :IBaseServer where UserType : IBaseUser
{
    public List<UserType> Users { get; protected set; }
}

public abstract class BaseUser<ServerType> :IBaseUser where ServerType : IBaseServer
{
    public ServerType server { get; private set; }
}

public class Server1 : BaseServer<User1>
{ }

public class User1 : BaseUser<Server1>
{ }
```

Comment: Can i do 
`public abstract class BaseServer<UserType> : IBaseServer where ...`
so i don't have to implement my interface in every BaseServer ?

Comment: checking for you - few mins

Comment: Updated my answer to the question in the comment.